# Vmware Workstation 8 on Gentoo - bridging additional NICs

Tags: linux, vmware-workstation

I recently installed a new dual port NIC into my Gentoo workstation. According to lspci:

```
10:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
Kernel driver in use: e1000e
```

I've configured them as bond1 and bond2:

```
bond1: flags=5187<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MASTER,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::215:17ff:fee7:bf10  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:15:17:e7:bf:10  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 363  bytes 64024 (62.5 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 29  bytes 2666 (2.6 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

bond2: flags=5187<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MASTER,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::215:17ff:fee7:bf11  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:15:17:e7:bf:11  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 5  bytes 320 (320.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 4  bytes 316 (316.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The interfaces themselves work fine, however when I go to define them as 'bridged networks' in VMware, I don't have the option (IE they aren't visible). I only see eth0 (or bond0 depending on my config).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do? State your objective *clearly*. a. expose both ifs to the guest and bridge them there? b. bridge the ifs on the host and expose the bridge to the guest? c. bond the ifs and expose the bonded if to the guest? d. something else? Why is Gentoo a factor?

Comment: Gentoo is special since it rolls it's own package for workstation. It's pretty clear in the description - the interfaces do not show up in the network editor. Virtualbox does not have this issue

Comment: Gentoo doesn't own that software. What are you talking about?

Comment: Never said it did, they have their own ebuild with custom patches for it...it's not stock. Go look yourself